# AngularJS Upgrade (1.5 to 1.6,1.7) Makes directive scope bindings undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-controller, angularjs-1.6

I have the following code:

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .directive('layout', function () {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          template: '<div ng-include="layoutCtrl.pageLayout"></div>',
          controller: 'LayoutController',
          controllerAs: 'layoutCtrl',
          bindToController: true,
          scope: {
              pageLayout: '=',
              pageConfiguration: '=',
              isPreview: '='
          }
      };
  });

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('LayoutController', LayoutController);

function LayoutController($scope, LayoutDTO, LayoutPreviewDTO) {
    var self = this;
    self.layoutDTO = LayoutDTO;
    self.layoutPreviewDTO = LayoutPreviewDTO;
    var test = $scope;

    if(self.isPreview)
        self.layoutModel = new self.layoutPreviewDTO(self.pageConfiguration);
    else
        self.layoutModel = new self.layoutDTO(self.pageConfiguration);
}


<div>
    <layout page-layout="ctrl.layoutTemplateUrl" page-configuration="ctrl.pageConfiguration" is-preview="false"></layout>
</div>
```

In the angular 1.5.3 version this worked as expected, the variables in my Controller were coming in with values.  Now, since I upgraded to 1.6.x, self.pageConfiguration is now undefined.

Nothing has changed except for the angular version.

How do I get a handle on the values passed into the directive in my controller?

Comment: Have you checked the Angular changelog for breaking changes that might cause this code "not to work"? And what exactly doesn't work - What error do you get? Did you also updated other `ng` native modules to the same version of angular?

Comment: self.pageConfiguration is now "undefined" instead of the values I passed in from the html        <layout page-layout="ctrl.model.layoutTemplateUrl" page-configuration="ctrl.model.pageConfiguration" is-preview="false"></layout>

Comment: Unfortunately that's too broad. Can you make a fiddle that reproduce the issue? Because it's hard to debug without knowing how you call this directive, etc..

Comment: There is an `edit` link under the tags of the question - Click on it and update the answer

Answer (score 18):

The AngularJS team recommends that controller code that depends on scope bindings be moved into an `$onInit` function.

```
function LayoutController($scope, LayoutDTO, LayoutPreviewDTO) {
    var self = this;
    this.$onInit = function () {
        // bindings will always be available here
        // regardless of the value of `preAssignBindingsEnabled`.
        self.layoutDTO = LayoutDTO;
        self.layoutPreviewDTO = LayoutPreviewDTO;
        var test = $scope;

        if(self.isPreview)
            self.layoutModel = new self.layoutPreviewDTO(self.pageConfiguration);
        else
            self.layoutModel = new self.layoutDTO(self.pageConfiguration);
    };
}
```

> $compile:
>
> Due to [bcd0d4](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/bcd0d4d896d0dfdd988ff4f849c1d40366125858), pre-assigning bindings on controller instances is disabled by default. It is still possible to turn it back on, which should help during the migration. Pre-assigning bindings has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version, so **we strongly recommend migrating your applications to not rely on it as soon as possible.**
>
> Initialization logic that relies on bindings being present should be put in the controller's `$onInit()` method, which is guaranteed to always be called *after* the bindings have been assigned.
>
> [-- AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating from v1.5 to v1.6 - $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-services-$compile)

---

## UPDATE

The `$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled` flag has been removed from AngularJS V1.7.

The AngularJS team **strongly recommends migrating your applications to not rely on it as soon as possible.** AngularJS V1.6 goes end-of-life on 1July2018.

From the Docs:

> Due to [38f8c9](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/38f8c97af74649ce224b6dd45f433cc665acfbfb), directive bindings are no longer available in the constructor.
>
> Previously, the `$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled` flag was supported. The flag controlled whether bindings were available inside the controller constructor or only in the `$onInit` hook. The bindings are now no longer available in the constructor.
>
> To migrate your code:
>
> - If you specified `$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true)` you need to first migrate your code so that the flag can be flipped to `false`. The instructions on how to do that are available in the  ["Migrating from 1.5 to 1.6" guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-services-$compile). Afterwards, remove the `$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true)` statement.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.7 - Compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#-compile-)

### Note:

On 1July2018, support for AngularJS 1.6 ends. For more information, see [AngularJS MISC - Version Support Status](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status).

Comment: OK, I will keep this in mind for future versions, thanks for pointing me to this article

Comment: @drabbitharv you should mark this as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/dfb8cf6402678206132e5bc603764d21e0f986ef

This defaults to false now, must set to true
$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);

Comment: this is a bad idea if you're trying to follow the migration path because all that does is switch it back to 1.5. As @georgeawg mentioned, you should be using $onInit() to correct your binding

Comment: The `$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled` flag has been removed from AngularJS V1.7.